# COUNT(*) with GROUP BY in a table with 30M rows

Tags: mysql, sql, bigdata

I have to extract data from a tables containing 30 millions rows.
The features from the table are visits_id(primary) survey_id company_id

I have to count the number of visits for every survey from every company knowing that a company can have multiple survey.

The query i made was:

```
SELECT v.survey_id, v.company_id, COUNT(*)
FROM visit AS v
GROUP BY v.survey_id, v.company_id
```

The main issue is that it takes soooooo long. Is there anyway to optimise the query?
Or is it something impossible to do for SQL or not worth the effort?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please tag your database and tell us exactly how long it takes. If you report the counts on a monthly basis, it might make sense to split the table into monthly tables and store the counts into another table that you can later use for reporting.

Comment: We have a MySQL database. It takes around 25sec just to make a simple SELECT COUNT(*) without GROUP BY.

Answer (score 7):

The most direct way to improve the performance of that query would be to add a compound index on `survey_id, company_id`.

The main drawback with adding indexes is that *writes* are longer. If that's a concern (or it's not worth it to improve this query) then you could pre-process the data periodically in the background and store the counts somewhere. Obviously you risk having stale counts.